# Reflexive relation of sharing with yourself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm looking at *Sets, Logic and Maths for Computing* by David Makinson and on page 56 is an example

> Identify the status of the following relations as
> reflexive/irreflexive/neither over the set of all people living in the
> UK: sibling of, shares at least one parent with, ancestor of, lives in
> the same city as, has listened to music played by.

Then, the explanation says

> The relation ‘sibling of’ as ordinarily understood is not reflexive
> since we do not regard a person as a sibling of himself or herself. In
> fact, it is irreflexive. By contrast, shares at least one parent with’
> is reflexive. It follows that these two relations are not quite the
> same. ‘Ancestor of’ is irreflexive. ‘Lives in the same city as’, under
> its most natural meaning, is neither reflexive nor irreflexive, since
> not everyone lives in a city. ‘Has listened to music played by’ is
> neither reflexive nor irreflexive for similar reasons.

For "shares at least one parent with," this relationship to be reflexive would have to be, e.g., I share at least one parent with myself. I see this as symmetric since two siblings can say that, but not reflexive.

Comment: Do you have at least one parent in common with yourself? Yes. So it is reflexive. It is also symmetric, but your reasoning is not valid. It is not symmetric because "two siblings can say that". It is symmetric because if $x$ has at least one parent in common with $y$, then $y$ has at least one parent in common with $x$.

Comment: I would think having a parent in common with myself would be like being a sibling with myself, i.e., nonsense.

Comment: You could argue it through cloning yourself, then looking at if you and your clone share parents, if you prefer, but this seems more an artifact of language, semantics, and culture than it does math in the end.

Comment: @147pm It is not at all nonsense.  "I am a sibling of myself" is  false, since by definition your sibling must be a person other than yourself.  "I have a parent in common with myself" is true, since my mother is my mother and my father is my father.  It is of course assumed that everyone does have at least one parent 
(Adam and Eve are not included).

Comment: At the end of the day, what matters most is not whether or not you agree with the wording and interpretation of the author here with regards to the semantics (*even though surely 99% of the people would agree with the author and you are in the minority*)... what matters is whether you understand the mathematical meanings the author is trying to convey.  Do you *understand* (*not necessarily agree with*) what the author was trying to say and do you *understand* what "reflexive" means in a mathematical context?

Comment: Rather than the examples given (*which were an attempt of coming up with relations that occur in everyday life*), would you be more comfortable with more "*mathy*" examples such as the set being the set of polygons embedded in $\Bbb R^2$, and giving examples of relations such as "$x$ has the same number of sides as $y$" or "$x$ has a side the same length as a side of $y$" etc...

Comment: Being my own sibling is not "nonsense", it is just false because of the meaning of "sibling". But "having the same set of parents as myself" or "sharing at least one parent with my myself" is neither false nor nonsense. It may seem like a *silly* assertion to make in every day life and one younwouldn't normally make (just like saying "I agree with myself" or "I own the same clothes as I do"), but it is nonetheless a true statement.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I would see a rewording into "my mother is my mother" as symbolically similar to $a = a$, and therefore, yes, a reflexive relation. The $a$ "is in common with" $a$ (due to me) relationship can then be generalized as "equals" or $aRa$. Still, it sounds strange. Is this what they call a tautology in logic?

Comment: Yes... a statement which is always true is called a tautology, and the intended interpretation of the statement here is one... however the relation in question is more interesting than just the ordinary identity relation.  Suppose Mr. A and Mrs. B have a child together.  Suppose they get divorced and then Mrs. B has a child with Mr. C, and that furthermore Mr. C had a child from a previous marriage as well with Mrs. D.  Now... these three children... I'll name AB, BC, and CD respectively.  AB shares a parent with BC... BC shares a parent with CD, however AB does not share a parent with CD.